# When creating a google actions the name not allowed and blocking me from Saving

Tags: voice

I am trying to create a Google Action and I am getting this error:

> Your sample invocations are structured incorrectly. Make sure they all
>   include either your app name or pronunciation, and trigger your app.

Even if I set the name to

> Dr. Detroit

and the pronunciation to

> doctor detroit

I'm totally confused with this.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: make sure your "Sample invocations" match what you put in the pronunciation section.

Comment: It is quite likely I was trying to link the API.ai application to a Google Actions app and they were not named the same, so not playing nice together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also got the same error. It comes because of the fact that your sample invocations does not include the full name of your app/action. Try to make it exactly the same and it might work. I got mine working the same way.

Comment: not sure exactly what fixed this, but I am calling it complete now.  I didn't put in enough info at top.  But I believe it was something along these lines.  I am now able to save it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because they all have to be of the form "Talk to <APP NAME>" or "Ask <APP NAME> about X", etc.

I agree that this is not made very clear, but this is what they mean by "… and trigger your app".

There's a list of allowed phrases here: https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales

Comment: this wasn't the problem as that is pretty straight forward.  At the time, it wasn't even allowing me to save the action.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error

`our sample invocations are structured incorrectly. Make sure they all include either your app name or pronunciation and trigger your app.`

What actually helped me is?

For the app `Dr. Detroit`

You can use **invocation** as `Talk To Dr. Detroit`.
*This will fix the problem.*

`Talk To` will help the app to get triggered.

Other **Trigger Phrases** are:

- "let me talk to $name"
- "I want to talk to $name"
- "can I talk to $name"
- "talk to $name"
- "let me speak to $name"
- "I want to speak to $name"
- "can I speak to $name"
- "speak to $name"
- "ask $name"
- "ask $name to ..."

From the reference doc:
`https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales`

Here is the ref link: 
**Build Actions for the Google Assistant** *tutorial* by **codelabs** 
`https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0`

**Google documentation on Action on Google**

`https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#linking_to_your_actions`

Answer (score 1):

This solved my same issue.

*View Logs* in simulator window. Expand log for *Sending request with post data* and make sure that inside *rawInpu*t element *query* attribute is matching with your sample invocation **(overview -> app information -> details -> sample invocation)**

Hope this can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the same name in the invocations as the full name of your application.

Comment: isn't this the same answer as provided by @Suyash

Answer (score 0):

In this case, make sure that Sample innovation name and display name should be the same.

Then there will be no error encountered at the release stage.